# How to Read information from an image of a card(credit,debit...)in android?

Tags: android, image-processing, ocr

The  requirement is to get information on the different types of cards such as  Credit ,Debit, License, SSN, medical insurances etc.
We need to get a photo from the mobile phone  then extract details of main fields (name and contact details of user, issuer’s main details if has mentioned and Card NO) and store within our application .

As i find Abby mobile ocr engine is a better solution.

But i need a open source sdk or api to resolve this problem. And also guide to do the installation on the windows xp and to do a very little example.

I searched on the internet couple of days, but could not fine a good solution.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may have seen this already but here is some good information about OCR using OpenCV which is opensource.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284214/simple-ocr-programming-tutorials-articles

Answer (score 0):

"I have a problem core to our business, please solve the issue for me." It's not a simple problem by any means, you're going to have to expend significant efforts improving your algorithm to read all sorts of different fields.

Best bet? Make the application take a photo and upload it to your service, you have much more flexibility and processing power there. Any existing partial solutions will likely be unsuitable for Android usage.